# Query MongoDb document by nested element

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I am trying to find the syntax to delete a mongoDB record using PHP, but every example I find on internet only shows how to do it if the deletion criteria is one level...

So if I have a mongoDB record like this:

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("50d69d6a1d26a8a0c1eaecf8"), 
        "name" : "John",
        ...other fields...
```

The I can delete it using the syntax:

```
$collection->remove(array('name' => 'John'));
```

This is fine, however my problem is that the key I need to lookup for deletion is one more level down.

So I have a record that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f2aaa3452a235c049000029"),
    "synthOrder" : {
        "orderId" : "899422",
        ...other fields...
```

I want to delete records in which orderId is say, 899422.
So what would my deletion line be like?

I tried:

```
$collection->remove(array('synthOrder' => array('orderId' => '899422')));
```

I feel it is a simple syntax issue, but I am not able to find any example online. I appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple, but perhaps an explanation. The query you are trying would only match a document that looked exactly like this:

```js
{
    "synthOrder": {
        "orderId": "899422"
    }
}
```

Meaning that there is only "one" element within the nested element since that is what your syntax is actually asking.

For this reason MongoDB uses ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) for referencing individual nested elements:

```
$collection->remove( array( 'synthOrder.orderId' => '899422'));
```

That allows referencing without it looking like an "explicit" document, which is what you were doing in the form you tried.